# How to do nested translation in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, translation

I am trying to do nested translation in angular with a conditional involved as well.

the setup:

```
<p translate-values="{partnerName: (enterPin.partnerName) ? enterPin.partnerName : {{'YourProvider'}}}" translate>
    {{'EnterPINCodeMessage'}}
</p>
```

Here is my translation file:

```
{
    "EnterPINCodeMessage": "Enter the 13 digit PIN code you received from {{partnerName}}. If you do not have a PIN code, please contact {{partnerName}} for assistance.",
    "YourProvider": "your Provider"
}
```

If enterPin.partnerName has a value I want `{{partnerName}}` to use that, if not I want `{{partnerName}}` to use the translation of `{{'YourProvider'}}`

With this setup, this is my result:

```
<p translate-values="{partnerName: (enterPin.partnerName) ? enterPin.partnerName : YourProvider}" translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Enter the 13 digit PIN code you received from . If you do not have a PIN code, please contact  for assistance.</p>
```

which is rendered as

> Enter the 13 digit PIN code you received from . If you do not have a PIN code, please contact for assistance.

How can I partnerName to take the translation of 'YourProvider' if enterPin.PartnerName is empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is what ended up working:

```
        <p translate-values="{partnerName: (enterPin.partnerName) ? enterPin.partnerName : '{{'YourProvider' | translate }}' }" translate>{{'EnterPINCodeMessage'}}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I havn't tried it, but I think the braces within the braces are the problem here. So instead of this

```
<p translate-values="{partnerName: (enterPin.partnerName) ? enterPin.partnerName : {{'YourProvider'}}}" translate>
    {{'EnterPINCodeMessage'}}
</p>
```

try this

```
<p translate-values="{partnerName: (enterPin.partnerName) ? enterPin.partnerName : 'YourProvider'}" translate>
    {{'EnterPINCodeMessage'}}
</p>
```

Comment: already tried this.  it gets rendered as: Enter the 13 digit PIN code you received from YourProvider. If you do not have a PIN code, please contact YourProvider for assistance.